# Complex query (for me anyway)

Tags: mysql

I've been at this for days and come close but no cigar.

A site user selects a category from a drop-down box. We need to check if there is a fee schedule associated with that category or with any category in the ancestry of that category and, if so, whether that user has sufficient credits to post a lead under that category. If there is no fee schedule, or the user has sufficient credits, user may proceed to listing their item.

Below are the relevant tables with some sample data to demonstrate the relationships

**all_categories**

```
record_id     level     title         parent_category_id     parent_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
24            0         Real Estate   null                   null
5915          1         Residential   24                     24
7569          2         For sale      5915                   24
10087         3         Apartment     7569                   24   
5691          1         Cars          7                      7
```

**premium_features** (Paid subscriptions)

```
record_id     title            
--------------------------
1             Auction Packages
3             Real Estate
4             Vehicles
```

**cat_feature** 
(categories specified for above subscriptions, if applicable, i.e. if you 
    want to list a product that comes under these categories, you need a 
    subscription. However, if you've purchased an auction package and you are auctioning 
    your product then you don't need to be subscribed under a particular 
    category)

```
category_id     feature_id
--------------------------
24              3
5691            4
```

**feature_options** 
(specific options you can select when subscribing. "Qty" is the number 
of instances you receive for the specific option)

```
record_id   feature_id   title                      type     price    qty
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          1            37 Auctions                auction  19.95    37
18          2            E-Store                    all      49.95     1
19          3            Private                    auction  99.00     1
20          3            Corporate                  auction  25.00     1
21          4            Private                    all      39.00     1
```

**user_feature**
"Remaining" is user's credits remaining

```
record_id   user_id     feature_option_id     remaining
-------------------------------------------------------
1           2           1                     36
2           2           21                    0
39          2           19                    1
```

Assume that the following parameters are passed to the function which runs the query (not all the params will necessarily be needed, e.g "level"):

```
user_id = 2
category_id =  10087
level = 3
type = auction
```

The messy code I have to date reflects my messy state of mind at this stage, and is as follows:

```
    SELECT T2.record_id as ac_catid, fo.type ,fo.record_id as fo_record_id, 
fo.feature_id as fo_feature_id, fo.title as fo_title, pf.title as pf_title, 
cf.feature_id as cf_feature_id, uf.user_id, uf.remaining
    FROM (SELECT @r AS _id , 
        ( SELECT @r := parent_id FROM all_categories WHERE record_id = @r ) 
        AS parent_id , @l := @l + 1 AS lvl 
        FROM (SELECT @r := record_id , @l := 0 FROM all_categories WHERE  record_id = 10087) vars 
        , all_categories m WHERE @r <> 0) T1 
        RIGHT JOIN all_categories T2 ON T1._id = T2.record_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cat_feature cf on cf.cat_id = T2.record_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN premium_features pf on pf.record_id = cf.feature_id 
        RIGHT JOIN feature_option fo on fo.feature_id = cf.feature_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN user_feature uf on uf.feature_option_id = fo.record_id 
        WHERE 1=1 
        AND uf.user_id = 2 
        ORDER BY ac_catid;
```

This gives me the following output if the above tables were fully populated:

```
ac_catid  type     fo_record_id  fo_feature_id  pf_title    fo_title  cf_feature_id  user_id  remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
null      auction  1             1              null        37 Auctions  null           2       36
24        all      19            3              Real Estate Private      3              2        1
5691      all      21            4              Vehicles    Private      4              2        0
```

The problem is that the query just returns what the user has signed up for. So it returns the "24" record simply because the user has specifically signed up for this (as per the user_feature table, i.e. he signed up for feature_option 19, which is related to premium_feature 3 via the cat_feature table). But, I want it to recognise the "24" record because it is an ancestor of the category_id they selected, i.e. 10087. I just don't know how to take this any further.

Note: If "auction" is passed as the "sale_type" parameter, then the feature_option table's "type" column must be "auction". If this value is "all", then the user does not have a valid subscription for that category.

My mind is so clogged with this, I don't even know if I've explained it well enough. Sorry. Please ask me anything that needs clarification. Unfortunately I'm pretty much stuck with the tables as they are.

Comment: why this question was downvoted? includes every details, well formated and clear question.

Comment: According to your example, user 2 did **not** sign up for 24, but for 21 instead.

Comment: He signed up for feature_option 19, which is related to premium_feature 3 via the cat_feature table. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you really have to do everything in one query? I.e. I.d either cache the queries related to things which rarely change (categories-related info) or retrieve that information first and other stuff later. Big hairy queries tend to become unmaintainable too easy.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be in one query. I'm open to anything at this point. Thanks for the input.